# Put open and close brackets in word document or notepad lines

Tags: brackets

In a Word document or notepad I have multiple lines of words one under the other, e.g.:

zignature puppy food

zignature small bites

zinger dog crate

zinger winger dog crate

I want them to automatically generate an open bracket at the start of each line and a close bracket at the end of the line, so they look like these as a result:

[zignature puppy food]

[zignature small bites]

[zinger dog crate]

[zinger winger dog crate]

Answer (score 0):

- In Word, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Find and Replace window
- Find what: `(?*)(^13)`
- Replace with: `[\1]\2`
- Click More, select Use wildcards

[image: IMG:]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Will try it Asap!